# How to delete workspace?

Tags: svn

How do I delete a workspace that I created in the wrong place?

I'm completely new to svn.  Just installed svnslik and got far enough to create a repository and then a workspace.  However, it added one more level of directory than I expected so I want to remove the workspace and recreate it.

Comment: I don't know if this was ok, but I finally decided to try simply deleting the workspace externally from svn - that is, using the Windows file system operations.  My new workspace seems to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem. Just delete the workspace directory using your current operating system's command. All the information that makes it a *Subversion workspace* is embedded in the `.svn` directory in the root of your workspace.

Unlike Perforce or ClearCase, the Subversion repository server does not track workspaces.